# How can I extract a pandas df cell value if other column's value matches a substring and not just equality comparison

Tags: python, pandas

So I need to extract a cell value for a row whose another column matches a pattern.

I have the following Dataframe df:

```
id    A               B           C
0  2018-A4-X     some_name  2018-09-02
1  2018-A3-X     some_name  2018-05-13
2  2018-A2-X     some_name  2018-02-18
3  2018-A1-X     some_name  2017-11-26
```

I want to extract the column C's value where column A's value contains string 'A4'.

I tried to do like this but it gives 'KeyError: True'.

```
a4 = df.loc['A4' in str(df['id']), 'C'].iloc[0]
```

So my output in the above case should be `2018-09-02`

Comment: df.loc[df.A.str.contains('A4'), 'C']

Comment: Its a dupe, too many questions on SO on similar lines

Comment: @Austin I accidentally, i was trying to say something, then realized say something else, then really nothing to say, then gave a bad comment, lol, :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('A4'),'C'].item())
```

Output:

```
2018-09-02
```

Use `loc`, then `str.contains` to `'A'` column to see if `'A4'` is in it, if it is, get `'C'` column, and use `item` to get the value.